# How can i remove parameters from url?

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
   <div id='op_name_config' style='display: none;'>
     <form action='config.html' method='get'>
        <input type='hidden' id='type_op_name' name='type' value='op_name'>
        <table align='center'>
           <tr>
              <td align='right' style='width: 1000px'>
                 <label style='width: 200px'>Grynųjų pinigų įnešimas</label>
                 <input type='text' id='op_name_idejimas' name='op_name_idejimas'>
                 <br>
                 <label style='width: 200px'>Grynųjų pinigų išėmimas</label>
                 <input type='text' id='op_name_isemimas' name='op_name_idejimas'>
                 <br>
                 <label style='width: 200px'>Grąžinimas</label>
                 <input type='text' id='op_name_grazinimas' name='op_name_grazinimas'>
                 <br>
                 <label style='width: 200px'>Avansinis mokėjimas</label>
                 <input type='password' id='op_name_avansinis' name='op_name_avansinis'>
                 <br>
              </td>
              <td style='width: 300px'></td>
           </tr>
        </table>
        <div id='Login8' style='display: none;'>
           <table align='center'>
              <tr>
                 <td width='200' align='center'>
                    <button class='btn config' type="submit" id='btn_confirm8' onclick='reloadAsGet()' >Patvirtinti</button>
                 </td>
              </tr>
           </table>
     </form>
  </div>
```

And when I submit i have very long url: http://127.0.0.1:3000/config.html?type=op_name&op_name_idejimas=44&op_name_idejimas=4&op_name_grazinimas=&op_name_avansinis=3

How can I hide everything after "?":type=op_name&op_name_idejimas=44&op_name_idejimas=4&op_name_grazinimas=&op_name_avansinis=3

I'm pretty new in programming,
maybe someone could help?
I only can use HTML and javascript and I need to send throught get method.

Comment: Change form method to post

Comment: @Akshay _I only can use HTML and javascript and I need to send throught get method._

Comment: Oh, missed that part @Berto99 ajax would be the best option here then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In first place, you can't, the `GET` method use the URL to send informations, so if you send informations, those will be in the URL.

BTW, you can use JS to delete them when the page is loaded:

```
<script>
(function(){
    window.history.pushState({}, document.title, location.pathname);
})()
</script>
```

Comment: So i just copy it, or i need to edit something in this svript?

Comment: @VItasSvigaris pretty sure that you just need to paste the script if you don't have JS code that are using the GET parameters (so those parameters are only used server side)

Answer (score 1):

> I only can use HTML and javascript and I need to send throught get method.

If you **must** use a GET request, add a submit event listener to the form, and make the request using `fetch`. Then do whatever you need with the response. Note that the parameters will still be visible in the DevTools console.

```
// todo: add submit event listener
const input1Value = "John"; // here you need to get the values from the form inputs
const url = new URL('https://example.com');
const params = { name: input1Value };
url.search = new URLSearchParams(params).toString();
await fetch(url);
```

Comment: @VItasSvigaris added an example. you still need to add some code.